# Losing Multiple Printers in Group Policy

Tags: printing, printers, group-policy, gpo

This involves an office that has a dozen printers.  For reasons we want users to have all the printers available when they log in.  I've been working on a group policy to accomplish this.

I will add multiple printers to the GPO in the Group Policy Management Editor per instructions, yet when I close the editor and then go back to to the GPO to update/edit/etc, it will list only the first printer I put in the GPO, none of the others.  Can I have multiple printers in a GPO or do I have to create 12 separate GPOs for each individual printer?

I've tried creating this under both Computer Configuration and User Configuration.

Thank you for your time.

picture of end result:

[image: picture of end result]

Comment: Your image contains errors and is un-viewable.

Comment: Weird, looks fine on my side. Does it say what errors?

Comment: Disregard.  Now it looks fine.